# Whenever I buy a camouflage for a gun in Counter Strike: GO it isn't in my inventory

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I bought a bunch of camos from the community market for the Aug. When I go into CSGO it says I have a new item in my inventory. However, when I go into my inventory it isn't there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://steamstat.us/) on the CS:GO section, the inventory is delayed at the moment. Please wait and it'll fix itself.

[image: Picture from steamstat.us]

There is also an official statement about this by the Steam Moderator KillahInstinct [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/492378265889745057/).

> **Inventory server issues**
>
> There appear to be some problems right now, as seen by the influx of posts regarding the same issues.
>
> **I'm sure Valve is aware of the issues and resolving them as we speak. Give it some time.**

Comment: **Here is a kind request: Don't spam KillahInstinct.** He can't do anything to fix it. He isn't a CS:GO dev or a Valve Employee, he is just a moderator.

Comment: More on this here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/3tyk07/csgo_just_ran_out_of_32_bit_weapon_ids_for_skins/